# Deadlock priority of SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions, database-administration

Does anyone know how to set deadlock priority of ssis packages? I am running a package where at the slowly changing dimensions task, it is throwing the deadlock error.

```
Transaction (Process ID 75) was deadlocked on resources with another process 
and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I want to set this priority to high so this error is not caused.

Thanks.

Comment: Did u tried considering Logon trigger for the database instance https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fb88f619-79f2-4d58-b1a1-8f573ccebdc6/how-to-set-deadlock-priority-to-a-connecting-session?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Hi, I will look into it for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had this problem before, so it is difficult to replicate on my side. But, I believe you should try changing the Transaction Isolation Level to see if that fixes the error. To do this, in the Control Flow, click on the gray background in order to show the package's properties in the properties window. Scroll down to Transactions, and you will see it in there.

Additional info on the subject:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-transactions

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. For me, it was indexes interfering with the SSIS. I deleted the indexes, ran the package and then, created the indexes again and now its running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

I was using a data flow task component in which there is a condition split with many outputs.

The problem was that more than one of these outputs was calling the same stored procedure(As the stored procedure was performing a lock on a specific db resource, I found myself with a parallel use of a same resource which is locked by the same procedure => The result is a Deadlock).

The solution for my case was to duplicate the data flow task and to make sure that in each of them and for the conditionnal split inside, I use only a part of the outputs so that there are no outputs which are calling the same stored procedure.

The number of data flow task component will be related to the coverage of all the outputs of my conditional split.

Hope this help.